# How do I use variables in PHP/HTML in an SQL INSERT statement

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-server

I am trying to get an html page run a php document that submits data into a table using sql. The variables are in the html page (I think, that's not my part of the project) and it runs the php document. these variables are not in the php anywhere other than this line of sql.

My code is probably very wrong here, and I'm not entirely sure how to go about this. What do I do for the VALUES? is the syntax correct? How do I import variables from the HTML/PHP into the SQL INSERT and VALUES statements?

I'm bit of a noob here, sorry.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (id, last_name, first_name, username, password, gender, age) VALUES ()";
```

Comment: INSERT => http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Comment: mysql or SQL-Server?

Comment: Can you please post your HTML code as well?

Comment: @Rhopercy The HTML is not my part of the project. It also has not been written yet.

Comment: @Jens I believe mysql

Comment: @JKelly You believe? You should know which database you use!

Comment: @Jens The thing is, we don't have the database yet. I'm assuming that it will be the same one as the last time we did this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you'll need to get the data using a request from a html form (read more here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp). You said that the html wasn't part of your project, do you at least know the name of the values being parsed to the php? If not you'll need to find out.

Next you'll need to get the values via php's `$_REQUEST` global array, eg: if the name of on of the values is 'name' then you would get it using `$_REQUEST['name']`.

In terms of inserting those values into your query, you could just jam them directly into the query string but I and others will very highly recommend you use parameterisation to protect against sql injection attacks: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. We aren't really concerned with attacks since this will work on a closed system. I don't really understand how I would put the value from the '$_REQUEST' into the query. I might be overthinking this.

Comment: So all you would need to do is set the value from the request array to a variable in php and then bung it into your query.

So if you wanted to process a name field you would use something like `$name = $_REQUEST['name']`. Then you can either use parameterisation to add the value: `$sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (name) VALUES (:name)"; $db_object->preapre($sql); $db_object->bindParam("name", $name);` Or, if you really don't think there's going to be a security concern, you can just whack the variable straight into the query: `$sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (name) VALUES ($name)";`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know, thank you. The security is not an issue because this project is not going to be available to the general public. But still, thank you for the information.